# "Don't let you being tired affect your enthusiasm" Is it correct

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english, gerunds

Well, I know that I can colloquially say:

> It has nothing to do with **you being poor**

The whole bolded phrase acts as a noun or gerund. Can I apply the rule so that the phrase acts as an object of a verb?

> Don't let **you being tired** affect your enthusiasm
>
> That led to **him breaking up with her**

Can I use it as subject as well?

> **You standing here** doesn't mean that you are the criminal.

Are these type of sentences confusing? or is it commonly used and well-understood? I'd like the answer to be according to the colloquial American accent.

Comment: In American English, "your being tired" is more natural in the proposed context than "you being tired".

Comment: "That led to him breaking up with her." is completely natural in American English.  Having "that" be the subject of the sentence, and using "breaking up" to refer to ending a romantic relationship, are both slightly informal, as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the genitive/possessive rather than the accusative/objective; that's a matter of preference, though. "Me being poor"/"my being poor", "him breaking up with her"/"his breaking up with her". Which is more natural will depend on dialect.

These are all examples of a **gerund phrase**. In such cases, the *-ing* form of a verb is called the gerund. Gerunds are often used on their own as nouns - "running is good for you". In that case, while they are still a form of verb, they function as a noun on their own, and have neither subject nor object. However, in a gerund phrase they can have subject, object, or both - and thus the gerund's nature as a verb is clearer, but the whole phrase acts as a noun in the same way that a gerund might on its own. It is certainly widely understood, and indeed widely used.