# adjective with "being" or before noun

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

I wonder if the following usage is right.

> You should remove the answer being bootless.

Is grammar of the sentence right? If yes, what is the usage of "being" here?
Does it have same meaning with "*You should remove the bootless answer.*"

Additionally, what is the difference between followed "being" usage and following one.

> It has nothing to do with you being woman.

At first glance I thought, *it has nothing to do with you are woman*. But when I open subtitle of the movie, it is written and said exactly as "being".

I'm a bit perplexed. I know "being" represents passive present continuous tense. However, I don't think the usages are related to it.

Comment: Your sentence does not make sense. To start with, _bootless_ is not a very common word in present-day English. Do you mean "You should remove the answer because it is useless"?

Comment: _Being_ is not always passive. It is passive in "My car is being taken away", but in your example "you(r) being (a) woman" means "...the fact that you are a woman".

Comment: @KateBunting where can I find source to study for _you(r) being (a) woman" means "...the fact that you are a woman_ ?

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/195183/dont-let-you-being-tired-affect-your-enthusiasm-is-it-correct